# How to make Vim open an already opened file where I ask it to?

Tags: vim, vi

Vim has an annoying behavior that I can't seem to condense enough to ask a search engine for a solution:

Say I have 2 windows open in tab 1, displaying `file_a` and `file_b`, and 1 open window in tab page 2, containing `file_c`. While in tab page 1, in the window containing `file_b`, I run the command

```
:e /path/to/file_c
```

What I want to happen is to open `file_c` in the current tab page 1 window, the one with `file_b`. What actually happens is that it switches me to tab page 2, which already contains `file_c`.

Apparently some people consider this a feature, but it's a pain to have to switch to tab page 2, close the `file_c` window, go back to tab page 1, and reopen it again. In other words it isn't my intention to just open `file_c`, I want to open `file_c` *next to `file_a`*.

How can I disable this "help" and get Vim to open a file where I tell it to?

EDIT: Changed "window" & "pane" to "tab" & "window", which seems to be the Vim terminology.

Comment: What do you mean by _window_ and _pane_? Is _window_ a Vim window, or a Vim tab page, or a window manager window? By _pane_ I presume that you mean a Vim window, is this true?

Comment: @AlexP, By _window_ I mean a Vim tab page. By _pane_, I mean the divisions of a tab.

Comment: Vim has garbage terminology. "tab" and "split" are easier to understand, and "buffers" if you're describing multiple files open in the same tab or split, where only one is visible.

Comment: Please edit your question to be coherent. Include a minimum number of steps to get Vim into the state you're in. If I have one tab with file_a and file_b in splits, and another tab with file_c, and I do `:e file_c` while in the first tab, `file_c` appears on the first tab and i am not sent to the second tab. You may have a plugin that's causing this behavior, or you may not be asking a coherent question.

Comment: @AndyRay: Vim has coherent terminology. A _buffer_ is a chunk of text, which may be or not be associated with a file. A _window_ is a view into a buffer; not all buffers have associated windows, and a buffer can be shown in more than one window. But yes, I agree, the original question describes unusual behavior. Normally, `:edit` will load the file into the current window even if it is already shown in another window.

Comment: @AndyRay, I blew away my .vimrc and the behavior went away. Thanks for the tip. I'll start bisecting the .vimrc to find the culprit. If you post your comment as an answer I'll be happy to accept it. Otherwise the bounty gets wasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the default behavior of Vim. You have a plugin or a configuration setting in your `.vimrc` causing this. You can quickly test things like this by running vim at the command line with no plugins:

```
$ vim -u NONE
```